# How to persist sign in until user log out on a react-redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-redux, jwt

I'm working on authentication with JWT for a simple `React-Redux/Node` project. The thing I'm having a hard time with is to persist log in once the user refreshes or closes the browser. The token is correctly being saved to local storage and it is still there after browser refreshes as it should. On my App.js file constructor, I added the function to dispatch the action `getLoggedInUser()`, should run `fetch()`, sending the token on the request header to the API which will, in turn, verify that token and send a response. However, it seems that my `fetch()` function is never being executed in my code and I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated. Below my code:

**authActions.js**

```js
    //persist a login when your user revisits the page
    export const getLoggedInUser = () => {
    console.log('here') // this is run    
    return (dispatch) => { //but seems this never runs
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); //doesnt run
        console.log(token) /doesn't run
        if (token) {
            return fetch(url + 'getloggeduser', {
                        method: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                        }
                    })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.error) {
                        localStorage.removeItem('token')
                    }
                    else dispatch(logInSuccess(res.user))
                })
            }
        }
    };
```

**App.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { getLoggedInUser } from './Store/Actions/authActions'

    class App extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log('app component mounts')
        this.props.getLoggedInUser();
      }

      render() { ... }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        getLoggedInUser: () => dispatch(getLoggedInUser)
      }
    }

    export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getLoggedInUser` is not an action creator, it does not return an action object, so it can't be dispatched. I guess you wanted to do something like this:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        getLoggedInUser: () => getLoggedInUser()(dispatch)
      }
}
```